# Normalizing eigenvectors when diagonalizing

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, optimization

Suppose your square matrix is symmetric and I want to diagonalize it. Why is it that at the end you normalize the eigenvectors to get your orthogonal matrix (actually orthonormal matrix)? Is this just something that is done for convenience (i.e. to have a basis of unit vectors)? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure that an orthonormal matrix is. That term is not used. The definition of orthogonal matrix is for the rows/columns to form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: So if I just want an orthogonal basis, then I don't normalize the eigenvectors and the normalization is simply to satisfy a defintion. Got it.

Comment: It is rather confusing that we say the vectors in an ortho*gonal* matrix are ortho*normal*, but this is the usual choice of terminology in most references. I prefer the term "unitary" anyway, it has the correct meaning in the real setting and extends to the complex setting as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of orthogonal matrix is for the rows/columns to form an orthonormal basis. The term "orthonormal matrix" is not used.

Comment: Oh, and I got the term 'orthonormal matrix' from lecture notes at MIT. So at least someone there uses it. Personally I Like it better than orthogonal, for orthonormal already suggests the normalizing part.